# The set of self-adjoint matrices with rational eigenvalues is dense in the set of self-adjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $M_n(\mathbb{C})_{sa}= \{ A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}): A^*=A\}$ denote the set of self-adjoint matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, equipped with the metric $d(A,B)=\|A-B\|_2 = (Tr(A^*B))^{1/2}$. Show that the subset of  $M_n(\mathbb{C})_{sa}$ consisting of self-adjoint matrices with rational eigenvalues is dense in $M_n(\mathbb{C})_{sa}$.

Let $M$ be the subset of  $M_n(\mathbb{C})_{sa}$ consisting of self-adjoint matrices with rational eigenvalues

I'm trying to use the epsilon-delta definition of dense here.

So I want to show that for all $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})_{sa}$ and for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $B\in M$ such that $d(A,B)< \epsilon$

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})_{sa}$. By definition, $A$ is self-adjoint.

So we have $(A_{ij})^*=\overline{A_{ji}}=(A_{ij})$, which implies $A$ is symmetric, and has only real eigenvalues.

We know that $\mathbb{Q} $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Now I want to use this to choose some $B\in M$ to show that $M$ is dense in $M_n(\mathbb{C})_{sa}$.

This is the part I'm stuck.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is it not Tr(A*B)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A^*=A.$ Then there exists an orthonormal basis $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ such that $Av_k=\lambda_kv_k$ where $\lambda_k$ are the (real) eigenvalues of $A.$ It means $$Ax=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\langle x,v_k\rangle \,v_k$$ There are rational numbers $\mu_k$ such that $|\mu_k-\lambda_k|<{1\over n^{1/2}N}$ for a fixed natural number $N.$ Define $$Bx=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu_k\langle x,v_k\rangle v_k$$ Then $$(A-B)x=\sum_{k=1}^n(\mu_k-\lambda_k)\langle x,v_k\rangle v_k$$ and $$\|A-B\|_2=\left (\sum_{k=1}^n(\mu_k-\lambda_k)^2\right )^{1/2}< {1\over N}$$

Comment: You welcome. We have $\langle Bx,x\rangle =\sum_{k=1}^n\mu_k|\langle x,v_k\rangle |^2\in \mathbb{R}.$ Thus $B$ is self-adjoint. Another explanation: the matrix of $B$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $v_k$ is diagonal with real entries $\mu_k$ on the main diagonal. Hence it is self-adjoint.